# Glassfish 4 -- displaying p:dialog is so slow on Solaris but not PC

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish, solaris

- JSF2
- Primefaces 5.3
- Glassfish4
- PC -- Window 7 (64 bits) Professional
- Solaris -- 5.10 Generic_142900-02 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-T1000 Solaris

I have a fairly complicated applications with many tabs.  Each tab displays one or two data tables.  When the user selects a row, a dialog window is popped up displaying the row detail.  The number of dialogs defined are about twice the number of tabs.

On my Solaris box it will take 5 seconds from when I call chain.doFilter() to when the first get method gets called in my code.  If I do the same test on the Glassfish installed on my PC, it will take .05 seconds.

What is going on ?  I put logging everywhere in my code and am convinced that the code is working right, just so sloooow on the Solaris box.

Even when I removed all but one tab and one dialog, it still tooks about 2 seconds on the Solaris box.

I've been pulling my hair out the last 2 weeks!  Any hint on what else I can do to debug this would be helpful also.

Thanks.

Comment: So it works on other versions of GlassFish? Did you try profiling the application?

Comment: Is your PC ten years old? Is there enough RAM on the T1000? Have you monitored its resources? (CPU, RAM, disk)

Comment: I figured it out.  Just by switching from glassfish4.1 to glassfish4.1.1, I was able to reduce the time from 5s to between 600 and 800ms.  Yes I did monitored the resources, but could not find anything interesting.  No I didn't profile the application because I don't know how to.  If I see more slow down I will certainly check this out.  Thanks.

Comment: If that fixed your issue, post your comment as a self answer and accept it. Note that for your comments to be notified to the users you reply to, you need to use @username in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @jiliagre, I'm answering my own question.  I fixed the problem by upgrading from Glassfish 4.1 to 4.1.1